# django search using raw mysql

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

i am trying to create a custom search engine with 4 fields of search. I want to search inside the mysql table.

*this is part of my views.py for the search, pagination and it lists the entire table data.*

```
def addview(request, table_id):
    try:
        table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=table_id)

        tbl_details = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name.name
        tbl_detail = AllTables.objects.raw(tbl_details)

        paginator = Paginator(list(tbl_detail), 100)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            details = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            details = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            details = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        q = request.GET.get("q")
        title_search = """SELECT * FROM """ + table_name + """ WHERE `Title` LIKE '\%""" + q + """\%' """
        # title_search = """SELECT id,description, MATCH (title)  AGAINST (""" + q + """ IN BOOLEAN MODE) " \
        #                FROM """ + table_name + """ ORDER BY id DESC;"""
        search_title = AllTables.objects.raw(title_search)

        return render(request, 'tables/table_list.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                          'details': tbl_detail,
                                                          'search': search_title,
                                                          'detail_page': details})
    except AllTables.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404()
```

*and this is part of my models.py with the dynamic table class.*

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class AllTables(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

the error that i get using any of the *title_search* from the views.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omega/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/omega/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/omega/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/srv/tester/tables/views.py", line 52, in addview
    title_search = """SELECT * FROM """ + table_name + """ WHERE `Title` LIKE '\%""" + q + """\%' """
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

I have been trying to get this search working for the past week and i ve been asking about it...using different types of methods. Ex: elasticsearch, haystack, etc...

***UPDATE***

i Did modify the views.py like you said. and i dont get no more errors...but i dont get any results either.

this is part of my *table_list.html*

```
    <h3>Search Engine</h3>

<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'tables:details' table_id=tbl_name.id%}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Title" type="text" class="form-control" name="Title" value="">
        <input placeholder="Url" type="text" class="form-control" name="Url" value="">
        <input placeholder="Description" type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
      <p>You searched for open sections of: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>
{% if search %}
    <p>Found {{ search|length }} section{{ search|pluralize }}.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for section in search %}
            <li>{{ section.title }}</li>
            <li>{{ section.url }}</li>
            <li>{{ section.description }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No open sections found.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I only did the title_search...the other one i m going to do after i get the title fix.. They are just there in the html.
Please help me in getting this search engine fix
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`q` is `None`

You need to handle the case where `q` is not in `request.GET`

```
q = request.GET.get("q")
if q is not None:
    title_search = """SELECT * FROM """ + table_name + """ WHERE `Title` LIKE '\%""" + q + """\%' """
    # title_search = """SELECT id,description, MATCH (title)  AGAINST (""" + q + """ IN BOOLEAN MODE) " \
    #                FROM """ + table_name + """ ORDER BY id DESC;"""
    search_title = AllTables.objects.raw(title_search)
else:
    search_title = []
```

Your input has the name `Title` but you are looking for `q` in `request.GET`. You either need to name the input "q" or look for "Title" in `request.GET`

```
q = request.GET.get("Title")
```

Comment: Thank you...it doesn't give me no more errors...but it doesn't give me any results when i search for title. I m going to update my question with the table_list.html code

Comment: Updated my answer - you should really use Django forms instead of hand crafting them and you should really use the ORM rather than performing raw queries

Comment: for some reason.. my request.GET.get is not working...i use print to see what prints out...and prints out None.  I wanted to you Django forms...but i was looking for some answers to get it working this way...and i couldn't find any answers....about making dynamic model